# Mobile Hybrid App - deploy error

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, android, hybrid

I am trying to build a test app with Mobile SDK in eclipse (the ones that is created with the command "forcedroid create"), I've managed all the steps and I don't see errors in the project. But when I try to run my application on a virtual device, I get a bunch of errors. This is the one looking as the source of the problem so far:

```
04-08 11:22:26.558: I/ClientManager:peekRestClient(2041): com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.ClientManager$AccountInfoNotFoundException: No user account found
```

..other bunch of logs..

```
04-08 11:22:27.468: I/SalesforceDroidGapActivity.authenticate(2041): authenticatedRestClient called with null client
```

In Eclipse I have my test project, a project with SaesforceSDK and a project with SmartStore. The dependencies are marked via Properties -> Android -> Library.

To resolve some other errors I added the following to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I didn't make any other changes, this should have been the sample project "out of the box"...

Have you faced this problem? Thanks in advance
T.

Comment: were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The errors were related to force-droid. I downloaded the source from git-hub, updated  with android update project -p . -t X and then ant clean debug the SalesforceSDK and Smartstore projects, imported in eclipse, imported AccountEditor and it was working.. I have no idea why force-droid was not working or what was broken inside of it.